# Combine 2 diffrent loops in c#

Tags: c#, json

Is there any way to combine 2 foreach loops?

I'm trying to get the value of “total” and “Na” from a JSON file in one loop but I doesn’t work.

I can’t find the value of “total” when I use “data.items” and I can’t find the value of “Na” when I use “data.total”.

I tried to use “data” instead but it doesn’t work either......

Code:

```
foreach (var p in jsonbject.SelectToken("data.items"))
{
    Na = "";
}


foreach (var f in jsonbject.SelectToken("data.total"))
{
    total = "";
}
```

## JSON code

```
{{

  "data": {
    "total": 125,
    "items": [
      {
        "Na": "hdbcjd213",
      }
```

I want to extract the value of "total" and "items" and save in the database.

In short, I want to write something like this:

```
foreach (var p in jsonbject.SelectToken("['data.total','data.items']"))
{
  total = "";
  id = "";

}
```

Comment: "_I'm trying to combine two json values_" How so? Your "total" is a single number, but your "items" is a collection of (numeric) IDs. How would you combine a single total number with a collection of ID numbers? **EDIT** and improve your question, explaining **clearly** and **unambiguously** how **precisely** you want those combined and saved into the DB...

Comment: "_I can’t find the value of “total” when I use “data.items” and I can’t find the value of “Na” when I use “data.total”._" Of course not, because the "total" element is not part of the "items" array in your json. And "Na" is rather obviously not to be found in "total" because "total" is just a number. Also, note that your so-called "json code" begins with `{{` which is actually not valid correct json (trying to read such malformed json would produce an error)

Comment: @elgonzo Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying the wrong approach.

1. The best approach would be to convert the data into a poco object

```
    public class Item
    {

        [JsonProperty("Na")]
        public string Na { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {

        [JsonProperty("total")]
        public int total { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("items")]
        public IList<Item> items { get; set; }
    }

    public class Example
    {

        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }
```

And then deserialize the data-

```
    var data = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Example>("{ \"data\": ...... ")
```

Now you can get the data using the object `data`. `data.Items`, `data.Total`.

So you can write -

```
foreach( var item in data.Items){
    var toal = data.total;
    var na = item.Na;
}
```

2. Alternatively, If you only need to do is to get the values, you can use `dynamic`.

```
var data = JsonConvert.Deserialize<dynamic>("{ \"data\": ...... ");

var items = data.items;
var total = data.total;

....

foreach( var item in data.Items){
    var total = data.total;
    var na = item.Na;
}
```

but for this approach you have to cast them again whenever you use them.

I hope this helps. If this is not something you are looking for, let me know.